# Run queries on Bigquery from Cloud functions

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a query from cloud functions and I read that I could call a scheduled query (on-demand) and I am running the code below but I am getting "Requested entity was not found." error message.

```
   def runQuery(transferid):
    #Source Name = 'projects/413410600298/locations/southamerica-east1/transferConfigs/61ae683c-0000-2bc6-bdb5-089e083412ac'   
    print('transferid is')
    print(transferid)
    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()
    projectid = '413410600298' # Enter your projectID here
    parent = client.project_transfer_config_path(projectid, transferid)
    print('parent is')
    print(parent)
    start_time = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time() + 10))
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(parent, requested_run_time=start_time)
    print(response)
```

Comment: Did you try with the projectID and not the project Number as your did?

Answer (score 0):

I change my variable parent so that it would be as below and it worked just fine!

```
parent = 'projects/413410600298/locations/southamerica-east1/transferConfigs/' + transferid
```